# IBM MQ sharedsubscription with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

I have a working nodejs application connected with IBM MQ using pub/ sub to receive messages sent on a topic. I want to now scale the application to have multiple instances running such that only one of the instances gets the published message. I could find out [sharedsubscription](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=functionality-cloned-shared-subscriptions) property mentioned by IBM, but I cannot find any reference details for a nodejs based implementation.

I am currently using [ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs) for connectivity, but any other library is also fine as long as it is nodejs based.

Comment: Shared subscriptions are only available in the JMS and XMS APIs. See my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536456/websphere-mq-topic-subscription-with-multiple-consumers/43537547#43537547) for details of an alternative way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @JoshMc, will it be correct to summarize that we will need to use GET instead of pub/sub as an alternative to `sharedsubscription`?

Comment: That is correct.   You can still publish  but the consumer would be pointed to a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is layer on top of the MQI, so you should use the MQI way of subscription sharing rather than the JMS way.

Look at the `MQSO_GROUP_SUB` option on the Sub call.

If you supply some of your code, I can update this answer to show you the updates you might need. I am not a Node.js expert, only an MQI expert.

Comment: How will `MQSO_GROUP_SUB` help in this situation, it seems you can only have a single subscription with the same topic string and correlation ID.  The docs state "When creating a new grouped subscription it must still have a unique SubName, but if it matches the full topic name of an existing subscription in the group, the call fails with MQRC_DUPLICATE_GROUP_SUB."  Am I missing something? Maybe the docs are wrong?

Comment: I didn't realise that he wanted identical subscriptions.